# Trying to figure out why my Rails alerts aren't working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I cannot find an officially documented list of alert types in Rails, for whatever reason. In my controllers, I am redirecting users back, and so far, the `redirect_back` helper doesn't seem to be adding my second parameter to the `flash` variable.

For example, this works:

```
redirect_back fallback_location: users_path, notice: "Added user."
```

and this does not:

```
redirect_back fallback_location: users_path, danger: "Deleted user."
```

Here's what my `views/layouts/application.html.erb` looks like when it comes to displaying alerts:

```
  <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
  <br /> 
  <div class="alert alert-<%= key_type(key) %> fade in">
    <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
      ×
    </button>
    <i class="fa-fw fa fa-<%= key_icon(key) %>"></i>
    <strong><%= key.capitalize %>:</strong> <%= value %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
```

The reason I have a `key_type` and `key_icon` helper is because Rails seems to use these alert types, like `notice`, that doesn't fit with my theme's alerts.

So I placed a `binding.pry` right after the opening of `flash.each`, and I can see that if I redirect_back with `notice` set, it hits, meaning there's something in flash. But I've tried redirecting back with `danger`, `error`, `warning`, etc. and none of them work.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I cannot figure out what actually gets set in `flash`.

If I set it manually before the `redirect_back` method, then it works flawlessly, like this:

```
flash[:danger] = "Deleted user."
```

but not with the redirect_back method.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try with `redirect_back fallback_location: users_path, flash: { danger: 'Deleted user.' }`, what do you get?

Comment: @SebastianPalma hey there! this actually works. thanks man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the official guides https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash

By default it handles only `notice` and `alert` and you can use anything you want with the key `flash`. The example uses `redirect_to` but I guess `redirect_back` uses the same logic for flashes.